# не сохраняет массив объектов класса

Tags: c++

Массив books заполняется, но после перехода в main массив очищается, и присваивается другой адрес. Как сделать, чтоб поиск происходил в заполненном массиве?

```
#define SIZE 4

using namespace std;

bool porivniannia(char* clas, char* my);

class library {
private:
    class book
    {
    public:
        char avtor[20];
        char nazva[30];
        int rik;
        book()
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 20)
            {
                avtor[i] = '\0';
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
            while (i < 30)
            {
                nazva[i] = '\0';
                i++;
            }
            rik = 0;
        }
        book(const char* avtor, const char* nazva, int rik)
        {
            this->rik = rik;
            int i = 0;
            while (avtor[i])
            {

                this->avtor[i] = avtor[i];
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;  
            while (nazva[i])
            {
                this->nazva[i] = nazva[i];
                i++;
            }
        }
        void get()
        {
            cout << avtor << nazva << rik << endl;
        }
    };
public:
    class book;
    book books[SIZE];
    library()
    {
        book books[SIZE] = 
        {
            books[0] = book("Іван Франко", "Фарбований лис", 1921),
            books[1] = book("Тарас Шевчкенко", "Кобзар", 1885),
            books[2] = book("Рудавський", "збірник задач", 2001),
            books[3] = book("Сканаві", "збірник задач", 1969)
        };
    }
    void search_avtor(const char* avtor)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= SIZE)
        {
            bool a = porivniannia(books[i].avtor, (char*)avtor);
            if (a) books[i].get();
        }
    }

    void search_nazva(const char* nazva)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= SIZE)
        {
            bool a = porivniannia(books[i].nazva, (char*)nazva);
            if (a) books[i].get();
        }
    }

    void search_rik(int rik)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= SIZE)
        {
            if (books[i].rik == rik) books[i].get();
        }
    }

};

bool porivniannia(char* clas, char* my)
{
    int i = 0;
    bool a = true;
    while (my[i] != '\0' && a) 
    {
        if ((my[i] != clas[i]) || clas[i] == '\0') a = false;
    }
    if (clas[i] != '\0') return false;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    library a;
    a.search_avtor("Іван Франко");
    a.search_nazva("Кобзар");
    a.search_rik(1869);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите: вы объявляете в классе массив `books`:

```
book books[SIZE];
```

но не трогаете его, вместо этого создавая в конструкторе **локальный** массив с тем же именем, который существует ровно до завершения конструктора:

```
library()
{
    book books[SIZE] = 
    {
        books[0] = book("Іван Франко", "Фарбований лис", 1921),
        books[1] = book("Тарас Шевчкенко", "Кобзар", 1885),
        books[2] = book("Рудавський", "збірник задач", 2001),
        books[3] = book("Сканаві", "збірник задач", 1969)
    };
}
```

Все понятно?

Comment: Ясно, большущее спасибо

Comment: Большое пожалуйста. Если ответ решил вашу проблему - закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый...